# When using Core Data "Transformable" attribute type to get a set of any primitive type, how to get an NSPredicate to check if this set is not empty?

Tags: swift, core-data

I use a `Transformable` attribute named `viewingDates` on a `Item` entity.

[image: Core Data attribute "viewingDates"]

Thus I can declare the property `@NSManaged public var viewingDates: Set<Date>` on the `Item` class.

But how to format a `NSPredicate` to fetch all `Item` where `viewingDates` is not empty?

Note: My database contains more than 15000 items and I would like if possible to avoid having to fetch them all before filtering them via `items.filter { !$0.viewingDates.isEmpty }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With transformable properties you can't filter fetch requests based on the property values, at all. Transformable properties are converted to `Data` when you save, and back when you fetch, but during fetch they're still `Data`. All you can really do is check whether they're null.

If this property were optional, you could check if it was null. But you cannot use a predicate that considers the contents of the property.